# Although exception in activity function, runtime Status is completed instead of failed

Tags: c#, azure, exception, azure-functions

In my AzureFunction code if an exception has occurred in my activity Function I see still `runTimeStatus=Completed` but in such a situation I would like to have `runTimeStatus=Failed`.
What should I do?

here is my Code:

```
[FunctionName("Durable_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")]HttpRequestMessage req,
            [OrchestrationClient]DurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            TraceWriter log)
        {
            // Function input comes from the request content.
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Durable_Orchestrator", null);

            log.Info($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }

 [FunctionName("Durable_Orchestrator")]
        public static async Task RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context, TraceWriter log)
        {
            try
            {
                await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Durable_Activity", "0");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.Info("ErrorOrchestrator");

            }
        }

        [FunctionName("Durable_Activity")]
        public static void DurableActivity([ActivityTrigger] string name, TraceWriter log)
        {
            try
            {
                logger = log;
                DoSomething(logger);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info("ErrorActivity");

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just throw the exception in your Durable_Activity:

```
[FunctionName("Durable_Starter")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")]HttpRequest req,
    [DurableClient] IDurableClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Durable_Orchestrator", request);

    log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

    var checkStatusResponse = starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);

    return checkStatusResponse;
}



 [FunctionName("Durable_Orchestrator")]
        public static async Task RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context, TraceWriter log)
        {
        try
        {
            await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("Durable_Activity", "0");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            log.Info("ErrorOrchestrator");
            throw;
        }
        }

        [FunctionName("Durable_Activity")]
        public static void DurableActivity([ActivityTrigger] string name, TraceWriter log)
        {
            try
            {
                logger = log;
                DoSomething(logger);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Info("ErrorActivity");
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After running your code, it is stopped at `throw` line with an exception description.And I can nit call `statusQueryGetUri`.

Comment: you do have another function which starts the orchestrator, right? can you provide the code?

Comment: weird behavior...since statusQuery is provided by another function. I've been using this way and works fine for me.

Comment: I have tested your new suggestion, but after an exception the code still remains in ActivityFunction. `log.Info("ErrorOrchestrator");` is not run

Comment: @Kaja there are retries implemented by the orchestrator. It should retry a few times before setting the runTimeStatus to failed

Comment: I got it: In my case I only should have `try catch`inside the orchestrator and not in activity

Comment: you can, as long as you throw the exception after handle it in the catch block